# How to pass a table to lua with c#

Tags: c#, lua, lua-table, luainterface, nlua

How to pass a table to lua  with c#

I'm using the LuaInterface，this is my c# code

```
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Text;
  using LuaInterface;

  namespace GetLuaTable
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {

              Lua netLua = new Lua();

              CShaprFunction cShapr = new CShaprFunction();
              netLua.RegisterFunction("CShaprConsoleLine", cShapr, cShapr.GetType().GetMethod("CShaprConsoleLine"));
              netLua.RegisterFunction("CSharpGetTableFromStr", cShapr, cShapr.GetType().GetMethod("CSharpGetTableFromStr"));
              netLua.DoFile("MyLua.lua");
              netLua.GetFunction("main").Call();
              Console.ReadKey();
          }
      }
      class CShaprFunction
      {
          public void CShaprConsoleLine(object obj)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(obj);
          }
          public LuaTable CSharpGetTableFromStr(string name)
          {
              Lua lua = new Lua();
              lua.DoString("a={\"test\"}");
              LuaTable tab = lua.GetTable(name);
              return tab;
          }
      } 
  }
```

this is lua code：

```
  function main()
    CShaprConsoleLine("Start")
    local tmptable = CSharpGetTableFromStr("a")
    CShaprConsoleLine(type(tmptable))  
    CShaprConsoleLine("end")
  end
```

But I get the result，the tmptable is function type not table type. like this:

```
Start
function
end
```

so how can I pass a table to lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same `Lua` object in both Program and CShaprFunction for this to work right because it is creating the Lua table in the lua enviornment and you can't directly move a Lua table to a different environment.

Here is an example that produces:

```
Start
table
end
```

I used NLua, LuaInterface's successor that is still being updated because I was having trouble with LuaInterface but it should work the same in LuaInterface.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using NLua;

namespace GetLuaTable
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Lua netLua;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            netLua = new Lua();

            CShaprFunction cShapr = new CShaprFunction();
            netLua.RegisterFunction("CShaprConsoleLine", cShapr, cShapr.GetType().GetMethod("CShaprConsoleLine"));
            netLua.RegisterFunction("CSharpGetTableFromStr", cShapr, cShapr.GetType().GetMethod("CSharpGetTableFromStr"));
            netLua.DoString(@"
            function main()
                CShaprConsoleLine(""Start"")
                local tmptable = CSharpGetTableFromStr(""a"")
                CShaprConsoleLine(type(tmptable))  
                CShaprConsoleLine(""end"")
              end
            ");
            netLua.GetFunction("main").Call();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class CShaprFunction
    {
        public void CShaprConsoleLine(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
        public LuaTable CSharpGetTableFromStr(string name)
        {
            var lua = Program.netLua;
            lua.DoString("a={\"test\"}");
            LuaTable tab = lua.GetTable(name);
            return tab;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400700/how-to-use-json-methods-inside-lua-script-and-execute-lua-script-with-c